# Convert long to char* const

Tags: c++

What is the right way to convert `long` to `char* const` in C++?

EDIT:

```
long l = pthread_self();
ThirdPartyFunction("Thread_Id_"+l); //Need to do this


ThirdPartyFunction(char* const identifierString)
{}
```

Comment: You might want to read [The String Formatters of Manor Farm](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill19.htm).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT:
The "proper" way to convert an integer to a string, in C++, is to use a stringstream. For instance:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << "Thread_Id_" << l;
ThirdPartyFunction(oss.str().c_str());
```

Now, that probably won't be the "fastest" way (streams have some overhead), but it's simple, readable, and more importantly, safe.

---

**OLD ANSWER BELOW**

Depends on what you mean by "convert".

To convert the `long`'s contents to a pointer:

```
char * const p = reinterpret_cast<char * const>(your_long);
```

To "see" the `long` as an array of `char`s:

```
char * const p = reinterpret_cast<char * const>(&your_long);
```

To convert the `long` to a `string`:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << your_long;
std::string str = oss.str();
// optionaly:
char * const p = str.c_str();
```

Answer (score 6):

Another possibile "pure" solution is to use **snprintf**

```
long number = 322323l;
char buffer [128];
int ret = snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%ld", number);
char * num_string = buffer; //String terminator is added by snprintf
```

Answer (score 1):

```
long l=0x7fff0000;   // or whatever
char const *p = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(l);
```

Comment: It's giving segmentation fault