# How to Pass an integer value in to (const char *str) function argument?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a number to string and vice versa in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290089/how-to-convert-a-number-to-string-and-vice-versa-in-c)
>   [how to convert from int to char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847237/how-to-convert-from-int-to-char)

I am getting a user input of integers and I need to pass them to an argument - Output(char const* str); This is a Class constructor. Can you please tell me how do I do this? Thank you

Comment: convert integer to string, using `lexical_cast`.

Comment: If you're taking user input, why not simply take it as a string? No conversion needed.

Answer (score 6):

In C++11:

```
dodgy_function(std::to_string(value).c_str());
```

In older language versions:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss << value;
dodgy_function(ss.str().c_str());

// or
dodgy_function(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(value).c_str());

// or in special circumstances
char buffer[i_hope_this_is_big_enough];
if (std::snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%d", value) < sizeof buffer) {
    dodgy_function(buffer);
} else {
    // The buffer was too small - deal with it
}
```