# converting integer into char explictly

Tags: c++, casting

I am trying to convert integer into character. I know how to convert character to integer like this `int(a)` where `a` is a character. But when I am trying to convert integer to character, it is giving me a symbolic value. Please help me out.

I am doing something like below. Thanks in advance.

```
int a=0;
char str1[20];
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
   //somecalculation that sets value in a everytime and stores in str1 
   str1[i]=char(a)-'A'
```

Well I am running for loop and setting values in `str1`. This is just little of my code.

Comment: Which character do you want,say, 5 to map to?

Comment: well i am runnig loop where i am calculating something and setting that one digit integer in character array everytime with new digit

Comment: Can you give an example of input/output that you're looking for? Should f(5) = '5', or something else?

Comment: You know that the value of 'A' is 65 and that that substraction is resulting in a negative value right?

Comment: Here you can find previous discussions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847237/how-to-convert-from-int-to-char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str1[i] = static_cast<char>(a + '0');`. This will convert a = 0 to '0', a = 1 to '1' etc. Consider the behaviour as undefined outside the range 0, ..., 9.

Comment: I was actually not taking into account 0 to 9 thanks it worked

Answer (score 0):

just use sprintf:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
//somecalculation that sets value in a everytime and stores in str1 
    sprintf(str1 + i, "%i", a);
```

since you noted that a is each time only a one digit integer, this should work, but this is not very error prone... normally you should check on how much digits were written:

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
//somecalculation that sets value in a everytime and stores in str1 
    if (sprintf(str1 + i, "%i", a) != 1)
        printf("expected to print only one character!\n");
```