# how to cast int from int[] to const char*

Tags: c++, arduino

like the topic mention.... for example

```
int[10] msg;

msg[0] = 1;
msg[1] = 2;

const char* a = (const char*)msg[0];      
const char* b = (const char*)msg[1];
```

It seem there is no value when I test by printf

I'm going to use it this way

```
char test[20];
strcpy(test, a);
strcat(test, ",");
strcat(test, b);
strcat(test, "\0");
mclient.publish("topic1/sensorAck",test);
```

The result show only comma

Comment: Codes less that 32 are control codes, 0x1 that is the value of *a is not printable.

Comment: You are casting to const char *, but what you do with it is wrong. 1 and 2 are not printable ASCII characters and you also need to be aware of the endianness of the system. Are you trying to convert an integer into a string?

Comment: Use `itoa` or some other func to convert `int` to `char *`.

Comment: can you give me a bit more explain or sample

Comment: Jongz, first state what you are trying to do?

Comment: that is what am I going to do in the question I want to sent message via test variable the data should be something like "1,23" and raw data is come by int[] msg so I need to extract it and combine it as char* because function require that

Comment: Are you saying you want to convert integers to strings? Do you understand the difference between the number `1` and the string `"1"`?

Comment: const char* a = (const char*)msg[0];  this is not mean I convert it to string ?? ("1")

Comment: @JongzPuangput No the actual `int` value of `'1'` is 49.

Comment: so, what should I do please advice the msg[0] is any number as you see 1 so , how can I get "1"

Comment: @JongzPuangput http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847237/how-to-convert-from-int-to-char

Comment: stringstream isn't valid in arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the C code to convert an integer into a C string.

```
int i = 1;
char text[12];
sprintf(text, "%d", i);
```

Comment: result is this "ê" instead of "1"

Answer (score 1):

strcpy and strcat both stop when they reach a '\0' character in the source string.  Since int 1 is actually 4 bytes (0, 0, 0, 1), it will stop on the first byte, because it's zero '\0' and never reach the '1' value byte.

Comment: It depends on the endianness of the system. It may reach 1 first.