# Convert to std::string and get const char * in one line

Tags: c++, string, object-lifetime

I have a number that I **need** to convert to a `const char *` (an API I'm using them requires `const char *` as input to many of its functions). The following works:

```
int num = 5;
std::string s = std::to_string(5);
const char * p = s.c_str();
```

as suggested by answers like those in [how to convert from int to char*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847237/how-to-convert-from-int-to-char), but it involves creating the seemingly unnecessary variable `s`, so I tried the following, but it doesn't work (p points to an empty string afterwards):

```
int num = 5;
const char * p = std::to_string(num).c_str();
```

Is there a clean way I can accomplish this? Why doesn't the second example work? The behavior is very similar to what happens if I made this obvious mistake:

```
const char * p;
{
    std::string tempStr( "hi" );
    p = tempStr.c_str( );
    // p points to "hi" string.
}
// now p points to "" string.
```

Which makes me suspect that the issue `std::to_string(num)` immediately goes out of scope or something similar because it's not used to directly initialize anything.

Comment: Why not just use the `std::string` and forget about the `const char*`? (A `std::string` is just a `char*` wrapped in useful code to do stuff so you don't need to)

Comment: That "seemingly unnecessary" instance manages the dynamically allocated memory that `p` points to. In the second example, that memory is deallocated immediately, leaving `p` a dangling pointer. Same in the third example, just a bit more explicitly.

Comment: @Galik Yeah I'd love to, but an API I'm using requires a const char* as an input to some functions which I use a lot.

Comment: Just pass `s.c_str()` every time you call the `API` (that's what it's for).

Comment: The scope is the area where a name is visible. There is no scope issue here. Changed tags.

Comment: The variable `s` is not unnecessary.  It is required to ensure the created `std::string` exists long enough that other code (like the API you're using) can safely use a pointer to its internals (such as that returned by `s.c_str()`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::string` encapsulates managing dynamic memory (created with `new[]` and `delete[]`). Let's break it down.

```
const char * p = std::to_string(num).c_str();
```

1. Create a `std::string` (with a human-readable representation of `num`).
2. Get the `new[]`ly allocated `const char*` to the string.
3. Assign that value to `p`.
4. Destroy the `std::string` → `delete[]` the allocated `const char*`.
5. `p` points to... deallocated data

If you are using a pointer, the data that the pointer points to **must exist** throughout the lifetime of that pointer.

So, no, there is no way around this other than `new[]`ing a copy of the string, which you will have to explicitly `delete[]` later. And at that point, you've thrown the baby out with the bath and have no need to use `std::string`.

Create a string that lives at least as long as you want to refer to its internal data.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `std::string` it does everything you want and everything that you would have to do manually if you don't use it.

When you need to pass a `const char*` to a `const char*` function simply use `std::string::c_str()` like this:

```
some_api_function(mystring.c_str()); // passes a const char*
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a function which returns a `char*` which holds your value and can be used to manage its lifetime.  The problematic version is broken because the `char*` points to memory which it does not manage.

For example:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> str(int32_t x)
{
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> res(new char[12]);
    snprintf(res.get(), 12, "%d", x);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use`std::string` everywhere and don't use `const char*` when not nessecary. They are basically the same thing. I use `const char*` only when I'm using a file-path.
  Use `std::string` everywhere and your program should work.

Comment: `using namespace STD` is not only a typo, it is inappropriate for use in header files (at global scope).  Not a good suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, Mr. John Saini. I figured it out, and I fixed it. Thanks for your down-votes and electric comments.